# What should I expect from ANC? (mixed feelings w/Beats Studio 3 Wireless)

Tags: mac, audio, bluetooth, headphones

I’ve recently purchased a pair of Beats Studio 3 Wireless and am trying to understand how ANC is supposed to work & how much sound it is supposed to block.
These headphones do not have a passive mode which, if I understand it, means when ANC is off they will actually let all sound from outside leak in (this is a big minus for me but it may be good if used outside).
With this pair, ANC off is acceptable only when home alone, otherwise the listening experience is too disturbed. When ANC is on, and someone is listening to a YouTube video on an iPad at 60% volume, I can still hear something that disturbs my concentration whenever the audio I’m listening to makes any pause. Still, if the audio is a continuous song, it is fine, I can listen unhindered.
Now for the big doubt: when using them for conversation/phone calls, ANC is useless as every noise outside is amplified even from different rooms in the house any time I’m speaking-that is, I am not listening-. Is this normal for ANC?
I am really confused so I am asking if someone with a better knowledge about the topic could shed some light on what I am experiencing.

Thank you

EDIT: this question is no longer relevant as I studied Beats' & ANC specs for a few days, compared them to many other models and found out they are not responding to my expectations.
What I need is a passive noise cancelling pair.

Answer (score 0):

The Beats Studio 3 Wireless basically has two settings for ANC - either it is on, or it is off.

ANC is automatically turned on when you turn on the headphones. In order to turn it off, you double-press the power button. After doing so, the small light on the left ear-cup turns off to indicate that ANC is off.

When it is turned off, that is effectively the "passive mode". I.e. any noise dampening that happens now is solely due to the physical properties of the headphones, as the material they're made of and it's shape will block some sound from reaching your ears.

With this type of over-ear head phone, you should not expect the same kind of passive noise-dampening as with a pair of in-ear headphones.

Remember that the perception of ANC is subjective. Whether this is good enough for you to hold a phone conversation or not is basically impossible for others to tell.

You seem to mention that outside noise is actually amplified when using ANC and you're speaking. ANC is not really meant to amplify noise. I would check that the setup you're using for recording your voice (i.e. for example VoIP software, Skype, Teams, or whatever you are using) is not setup to cause an echo-effect where you hear your own voice back.

Comment: From what I understood in several reviews, the off version of the ANC for these Beats is similar to what would have become “Transparency Mode”. My experience was that, with ANC off, the microphones where amplifying a person’s voice whispering to Siri in a room with a closed door, something I would have not heard “without” the headphones themselves!! With ANC on, if I was the one speaking the same amplifying happened.
Discord had no settings for “echo”, didn’t try other softwares. 
Is there any BT headphone which is over-ear, no ANC & good PassiveNC?

Comment: Can you link to such a review? - I have never heard that. This model does not support Transparency Mode. When you turn the ANC off, it is off.

Comment: I’ll try to find it again. I’m glad you said this should not happen, I’ll make some tests to reproduce the issue, contact Apple about that and see if something is wrong with my exemplar.